# Is the Azure Read API configurable?

Tags: azure, ocr

I want to extract structured text from PDF contracts with the [Microsoft Azure Read API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text#read-api).

Is the service configurable? For example, can I set the minimum vertical blank space the system uses to split paragraphs?

Thank you!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? as per the documentation, there are no such params to pass. https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-ga/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005